# Converting from base-32 to decimal without VBA

Tags: ms-access

I've been searching and searching and my Google-fu has failed me. I'm trying to convert an encoded number from base-32 to decimal using either expressions or a macro, but I'm not finding anything. I know Excel has the "Decimal" function, I've been hoping that I could stumble onto something similar.

I'm reluctant to use VBA as I don't want to spend time re-learning the language right now and I'm worried that my organization will flag it as potentially dangerous (which could kill my attempts at making *any* databases).

With an input of `"16O9E55"`
I expect a result of `1300543653`.

I should clarify that this is "base32hex" according to Wikipedia. It's 0-9, A-V. It's only 7 characters of base-32 that needs to convert to 10 digits of decimal. My use case is decoding a barcode into the data I need.

Comment: Can you give an example of such an encoded number? Usually Base32 or Base64 is used to encode binary data and to make it a string that can be stored or transmitted easily. A number would usually simply be stored as formatted string. What exactly is encoded? The bytes this number is made of or the string bytes? How many bytes? Is it a 32-integer, 64-integer a Double a Decimal? If you have a string like `"12345"` it is not Base32 encoded and you can simply convert it with `CLng("12345")`.

Comment: I should clarify that this is "base32hex" according to Wikipedia. It's 0-9, A-V. It's only 7 characters of base-32 that needs to convert to 10 digits of decimal. My use case is decoding a barcode into the data I need.
An example number to decode is 16O9E55. I know that's 1300543653.

Comment: As you talk about databases, you maybe consider to use Microsoft SQL Server as the back end. Then you could use it to convert the values: https://gist.github.com/rmalayter/3976537

Comment: I'm just an office manager, I don't have the permissions (or pull with leadership) to get alternative software installed. Plus, it's going to be a pretty small local database, so I didn't see the need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this can be accomplished without VBA. Consider code adapted from https://www.excelbanter.com/excel-worksheet-functions/150198-formulat-convert-base-32-decimal.html

```
Public Function Base32ToDec(Num As String) As Variant

Static Digits As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim myIndex As Integer
Dim myStr As String

Digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"
For i = Len(Num) To 1 Step -1
    myStr = Mid(Num, i, 1)
    myIndex = InStr(Digits, myStr) - 1
    Base32ToDec = Base32ToDec + myIndex * 32 ^ (Len(Num) - i)
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: This is a really clever solution. Though, I found a more compact (I don't know if it's better) way to do it: 



`Public Function ReadNumber(Start As Integer, Length As Integer) As Double
    ReadNumber = worksheetfunction.Decimal(Read(Start, Length), 32)
End Function`

Unfortunately, it looks like I'll have to use VBA for this, so into the learning of a new language I go. :/

Comment: I was avoiding worksheet functions because requires activating Excel reference library. I tried your code and get error on Read() function.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm too novice a programmer to understand why activating the Excel reference library is a bad thing. Would you kindly explain?

And that function is out of a code block I found, I forgot about the "Read" function, so here that is: `Private Function Read(Start As Integer, Length As Integer) As String
    Read = TRIM(MID(Barcode, Start, Length))
End Function`

Comment: Activating libraries is not a bad thing unless you give db to someone who doesn't have that library - perhaps they have an older version of application. If that is not a concern then certainly use Excel library. I was keeping my answer simple so I did not have to instruct about activating Excel library.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) uses a 32-character set comprising the twenty-six upper-case letters A–Z, and the digits 2–7. The variant [base32hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#base32hex) starts with 0 - 9 and uses the letters A to V.

If only numbers with a limited range have been encoded, you can decode them easily with VBA, otherwise you would have to return an array of bytes and process it further.

You write, that you have up to 10 decimal digits. The question is, what the maximum number is. The `Long` type can store numbers up to `2,147,483,647`. This are ten digits; however, with 10 digits you could store a number as big as `9,999,999,999`.

Therefore, the following function returns the number as `Double`. If you know that your number will never exceed `2,147,483,647`, then you can exchange the `Double` type by `Long` for the `sum` variable and the function return type.

```
Public Function DecodeBase32hex(ByVal encoded As String) As Double
    Dim ch As String
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim d As Long, i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Len(encoded)
        ch = Mid$(encoded, i, 1)
        If ch >= "A" And ch <= "Z" Then
            d = Asc(ch) - Asc("A") + 10
        ElseIf ch >= "0" And ch <= "9" Then
            d = Asc(ch) - Asc("0")
        Else
            Exit For 'E.g. padding charachters
        End If
        sum = 32 * sum + d
    Next i
    DecodeBase32hex = sum
End Function
```

Test in Access' immediate window:

```
?DecodeBase32hex("16O9E55")    
 1300543653
```